# Using lodash and need to find names in an array that have an age less than X

Tags: javascript, lodash

so I've got this Array

```
var gillFamily = [{name: 'john', age: 20}, 
                  {name: 'richard', age: 27}, 
                  {name: 'debbie', age: 55},
                   {name: 'dan', age 25},
                   {name: 'robin', age 60}]
```

And using lodash need to find all the people with an age less than 50.
I tried this _.map to see if it would work

```
_.map(gillFamily, (el) => el.name, (el) => el.age < 50);
```

and some filter and reduce stuff with functions but cant get it, Thanks.

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter()` would be enough

Answer (score 1):

`_.map()` transforms an array. It does not remove elements. For example, if your input array is

```
const family = [
    {name: 'john', age: 20},
    {name: 'richard', age: 27},
    {name: 'debbie', age: 55},
    {name: 'dan', age: 25},
    {name: 'robin', age: 60}
]
```

you could use it to transform it into an array containing descriptions of the persons:

```
_.map(family, p => p.name + " is " + p.age + " years old")
```

You'll end up with:

```
[ 
    'john is 20 years old',
    'richard is 27 years old',
    'debbie is 55 years old',
    'dan is 25 years old',
    'robin is 60 years old'
]
```

To get an array containing the persons younger than 50, one way would be to use `_.filter()`:

```
_.filter(family, p => p.age < 50)
```

However, this isn't the only way to do it. There are a number of other ways to achieve the same thing using lodash, and ES6 also provides `map()` and `filter()` [natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `filter` function. filter function iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements where the condition is met. More information [here](http://terates%20over%20elements%20of%20collection,%20returning%20an%20array%20of%20all%20elements%20predicate%20returns%20truthy%20for.).

`map` is used to transform the array from one form to another which doesn't meet your requirement.

```js
 var gillFamily = [{name: 'john', age: 20}, 
                      {name: 'richard', age: 27}, 
                      {name: 'debbie', age: 55},
                       {name: 'dan', age: 25},
                       {name: 'robin', age: 60}];



var ageLessThan50 = _.filter(gillFamily, person => person.age < 50);
console.log(ageLessThan50);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```